# Set image in Imageview where the path of the image is stored in sqlite database and the actual image is stored in drawable

Tags: android

i am developing a android dictionary app.i have no problem retrieving text from sqlite database and displaying it in textview but i have got some problem while trying to save the path of the images in database (Storing the actual image in drawable resource folder) and set the image in Imageview.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_definition);

    String term=getIntent().getStringExtra("TERM");
    String acronyms=getIntent().getStringExtra("ACRONYMS");
    String wordclass=getIntent().getStringExtra("WORDCLASS");
    String dzongkha=getIntent().getStringExtra("DZONGKHA");
    String defintion=getIntent().getStringExtra("DEFINITION");
    String category=getIntent().getStringExtra("CATEGORY");
    String image=getIntent().getStringExtra("IMAGE");


    TextView termText= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.termtext);
    TextView acronymsText= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.acronymstext);
    TextView wordclassText= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wordclasstext);
    TextView dzongkhaText= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dzongkhatext);
    TextView categoryText= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.categorytext);
    TextView definitionText= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.definitiontext);
    ImageView imageText=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagetext);


    termText.setText(term);
    acronymsText.setText(acronyms);
    wordclassText.setText(wordclass);
    dzongkhaText.setText(dzongkha);
    categoryText.setText(category);
    definitionText.setText(defintion);
    imageText.setImage(image);

    }
    }


    Code for sqlite transactions

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public Context context;
    public TextView termText;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView, final Context context) {
    super(itemView);
    this.context=context;
    termText=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.termtext);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int position=getAdapterPosition();
                DictionaryModel dictionaryModel=data.get(position);

                Intent intent=new Intent(context, DefinitionActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("TERM",dictionaryModel.getTerm());

              intent.putExtra("DEFINITION",dictionaryModel.getDefinition());
                intent.putExtra("ACRONYMS",dictionaryModel.getAcronyms());
                intent.putExtra("WORDCLASS",dictionaryModel.getWordclass());
                intent.putExtra("DZONGKHAEQUIVALENT",dictionaryModel.
                getDzongkhaequivalent());
                intent.putExtra("CATEGORY",dictionaryModel.getCategory());
                intent.putExtra("IMAGE",dictionaryModel.getImage());

                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

whenever a user clicks on a term in the listview i want it to show the related text descriptions and the image from the database.

Comment: what is u r issue?

Comment: Please post the code which you have tried for SQLite transactions

Comment: I have no idea how to set the image path in database column(string) to ImageView.@DKV

Comment: I have tried the solution 1 but it says setImageResource(int) in imageview cannot be applied to (java.lang.string) @Abhinav Gupta

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION 1 :**

Use :

```
imageText.setImageResource(image);
```

instead of :

```
imageText.setImage(image);
```

**SOLUTION 2 :**

USE `Picasso` Library:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

do in java :

```
Picasso.with(context).load(image).into(imageText);
```